# find $\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{2x -\sqrt{x^2 +3}}{\sqrt{x+3} \ -\sqrt{2x+2}}$ without l'hospital rule

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits-without-lhopital

**EDITED VERSION**

find $$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{2x -\sqrt{x^2 +3}}{\sqrt{x+3} 
   \ -\sqrt{2x+2}}$$ without l'hospital rule.

using l'hospital rule, you'll have: $\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{2x -\sqrt{x^2 +3}}{\sqrt{x+3} 
   \ -\sqrt{2x+2}} = -6$.

I can show my attempt but it's pointless as the result i achieved $+\infty$, which is very wrong. is there an strategy trying to calculate a limit without l'hospital rule.

Comment: You can't use L'Hopital's Rule to solve the above limit problem because you don't have an indeterminate form. Just plug $x=1$ in the above expression

Comment: I think it's $\color{red}{-}$ in the denominator...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression tends to $$\frac{2\cdot1-\sqrt{1^2+3}}{\sqrt{1+3}+\sqrt{2\cdot1+2}}=0.$$

You *may not* use L'Hospital here.
(Or is there a typo in the question ?)

---

**Update:**

$$\frac{2x-\sqrt{x^2+3}}{\sqrt{x+3}-\sqrt{2x+2}}=\frac{\sqrt{x+3}+\sqrt{2x+2}}{2x+\sqrt{x^2+3}}\cdot \frac{4x^2-x^2-3}{x+3-2x-2}\to\frac{4}{4}(-6).$$

Comment: There was a typo. Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible that you meant $\sqrt{x^2 + 3}$ and not $\sqrt{x^3 +3}$?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what did you do in this solution

Comment: @Jneven: sorry, I made an inversion.

Answer (score 2):

I will assume that you meant$$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{2x-\sqrt{x^2+3}}{\sqrt{x+3}-\sqrt{2x+2}}.$$Multiplying the numerator and the denominator by $\sqrt{x+3}+\sqrt{2x+2}$, this becomes$$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\left(2x-\sqrt{x^2+3}\right)\left(\sqrt{x+3}+\sqrt{2x+2}\right)}{1-x}.$$So, define $f(x)$ as $2x-\sqrt{x^2+3}$ and then the limit that you're after is just$$-f'(1)\left(\sqrt{1+3}+\sqrt{2+2}\right)=-4f'(1)$$(which is $-6$ indeed).

Answer (score 1):

Starting from J.C.Santos result

$$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\left(2x-\sqrt{x^2+3}\right)\left(\sqrt{x+3}+\sqrt{2x+2}\right)}{1-x}.$$

I'd multiply num and den by $\left(2x+\sqrt{x^2+3}\right)$ to get

$$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\left(4x^2-x^2-3\right)\left(\sqrt{x+3}+\sqrt{2x+2}\right)}{(1-x)\left(2x+\sqrt{x^2+3}\right)}.$$
that is
$$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{3(x+1)(x-1)\left(\sqrt{x+3}+\sqrt{2x+2}\right)}{(1-x)\left(2x+\sqrt{x^2+3}\right)}.$$
and then
$$-\lim_{x\to1}\frac{3(x+1)\left(\sqrt{x+3}+\sqrt{2x+2}\right)}{\left(2x+\sqrt{x^2+3}\right)}=-\frac{24}{4}=-6$$

Answer (score 0):

Multiplying the top and the Bottom by $ \left(2x+\sqrt{x^2+3}\right)\left(\sqrt{x+3}+\sqrt{2x+2}\right) $, gives the following :

\begin{aligned} \lim_{x\to 1}{\frac{2x-\sqrt{x^2+3}}{\sqrt{x+3}-\sqrt{2x+2}}}&=\lim_{x\to 1}{\frac{-3\left(x+1\right)\left(\sqrt{2x+2}+\sqrt{x+3}\right)}{\sqrt{x^{2}+3}+2x}}\\ &=\frac{-3\left(1+1\right)\times\left(\sqrt{2\times 1+2}+\sqrt{1+3}\right)}{\sqrt{1^{2}+3}+2\times 1}\\ \lim_{x\to 1}{\frac{2x-\sqrt{x^2+3}}{\sqrt{x+3}-\sqrt{2x+2}}}&=-6 \end{aligned}